# MongoDB sort() removes documents that don't contain sort filter

Tags: php, javascript, mongodb

I am having a issue using MongoDB's .sort() as it removes documents that don't have the sorting field.

For example, I have an array of documents some containing a 'timeSent' field and some not:

```
db.foo.find() = 
    {
      "_id": { "$oid" : "51f25e497363055d1fde7524" },
      "eventID": 159,
      "timeSent": 1374844250464
    }
    {
      "_id": { "$oid" : "51f25e497363055d1fde7525" },
      "eventID": 158,
      "timeSent": 1374844250465
    }
    {
      "_id": { "$oid" : "51f25e497363055d1fde7526" },
      "eventID": 157
    }
```

Using .sort() removes the documents where 'timeSent' doesn't exists.

> db.foo.find().sort({ "timeSent": 1}).skip(0).limit(30)

I was wondering if there was a way in Mongo sort and return the full document like SQL. (Sorted 'timeSent existing' fields at the top and 'timeSent not existing' at the bottom. Or visa versa depending on ASC or DESC)

Thanks

p.s. Been trying to achieve this in PHP using MongoCursor.

Comment: Have you tried this find&sort from mongo's console? I did a quick test and documents with absent fields present in the result.

Comment: I'd check if my version of mongoDB is up to date, and if I am using up to date drivers. Mongo sort command returns documents even where the sort key is not present.

Comment: Thanks, I'v checked that the version is the latest of MongoDB. - I found the issue happens when I ensureIndex. If you try it with the command below, it removes where the key is not present. db.foo.ensureIndex({'timeSent':1},{'unique':true,'sparse':true,'dropDups':true}) Any thoughts?

Comment: @Jason that explains it. That is what a sparse index is supposed to do. You might want to rethink your indexing.. If you want an index in that attribute, you can set it to null on documents where there is no data for that attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mongo is probably using a [`sparse`](http://nofatclips.tumblr.com/post/52210243033/sparse-indexes-in-mongodb) index on the filtered field that you previously defined: use `explain` on the cursor to be sure.

You can either tell Mongo [not to use that index](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.hint.php), or rebuild the index including the fields without the key (that is, you [create a non `sparse` index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-sparse-index/)).

(Sorry about the previous answer, I got it backwards...)